# Select email address only (SQL)

Tags: sql

i have column in a table (column name is “from”), looks like this

```
blabla@hotmail.com
frank ocean real frankocean@mail.com
ari@gold.com
frits west f.west@mail.com
```

I want to select the email addresses only, how do i do this? with a substring?
I can find a domain, but i want to have the complete mail addresses, like this:

```
blabla@hotmail.com
frankocean@mail.com
ari@gold.com
f.west@mail.com
```

thanks!

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which rdbms you're using, but apart from that i would advise to store this separately in case you have influence over that.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the string and look for a space before the address: try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Addresses (EmailAddress VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Addresses (EmailAddress)

SELECT 'blabla@hotmail.com'
UNION
SELECT 'frank ocean real frankocean@mail.com'
UNION
SELECT 'ari@gold.com'
UNION
SELECT 'frits west f.west@mail.com'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(EmailAddress, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(' ' + EmailAddress),CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(' '+emailAddress)))))) FROM #Addresses
```

EDIT: if you have any strings that contain the name after the address, you can use the following to strip out the address:

```
CREATE TABLE #Addresses (EmailAddress VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Addresses (EmailAddress)

SELECT 'blabla@hotmail.com'
UNION
SELECT 'frank ocean real frankocean@mail.com'
UNION
SELECT 'ari@gold.com'
UNION
SELECT 'frits west f.west@mail.com'
UNION 
SELECT 'me@me.com my name'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(EmailAddress, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(' ' + EmailAddress),CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(' '+emailAddress)))), CHARINDEX(' ', EmailAddress + ' '))) FROM #Addresses


DROP TABLE #Addresses
```

EDIT 2: forgot to add trimming functions

EDIT 3:  final code using the OP's column name (table name not posted):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(RIGHT([From], CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(' ' + [From]),CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(' '+[From])))), CHARINDEX(' ', [From]+ ' '))) FROM -- whatever your table is named
```

Comment: Just use the SELECT portion, replacing EmailAddress with the name of your column and #Addresses with your table. If you'll give me the name of the table, I can edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is always in the format that you gave, then hopefully this will work:

```
SELECT RIGHT([From], CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(' ' + [From])) - 1) AS [Result]
FROM   YourTable
```

This will only work if there is a space before the input that you want (the actual email address). I use this for a similar purpose in for some legacy dodgy customer data.

*This is for SQL Server, I don't know if it will work for any other RDBMS.*